# emmet-abbreviations-not-working-with-react-on-VScode

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

[image]

When I am trying to write these shortcuts it's not working in reactJs. Already setting I have added
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
"javascript": "javascriptreact"
}
still, it's not working. any solution for this exact problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer: https://eshwaren.medium.com/enable-emmet-support-for-jsx-in-visual-studio-code-react-f1f5dfe8809c

Also try restarting your VSC after modifying the settings.json, I got that one too.

Comment: but for div*3, ul>li*3  it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

For VScode version 1.69.0 div * 5 it's not working. Even ul>li * 4 is not working. for making it workable. we have to write like this div * 5 ctrl+space or ul>li * 5 ctrl+space, select from the drop-down, and hit enter. It is working 100%.